# BigQuery LOAD does not produce default values when importing JSON

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I got stuck when trying to let BigQuery generate default values in the process of loading data from JSON.

I start with this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `project_name.dataset_name.table_name` (
  a STRING,
  b TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

When I insert a new row as below, the default timestamps are created:

```sql
INSERT INTO `project_name.dataset_name.table_name` (a)
VALUES ('whatever');
```

However, when importing data via LOAD DATA from a JSON source (as below), the default values are not created but `null`. The JSON source only contains data on `a`, and I would like to have `b` populated by BigQuery.

```sql
LOAD DATA INTO `project_name.dataset_name.table_name`
FROM FILES (
  format = 'JSON',
  uris = ['gs://.../test.json']);
```

Is there a way to produce default values when loading from JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your steps and here's one change I made to LOAD DATA command. Here I have defined the schema too and hence the default at table level worked.

```
LOAD DATA INTO `myproject.zz_DataSet.tblDefaultColumnTest` (a string)
FROM FILES (
  format = 'JSON',
  uris = ['gs://for-bihag-pocs/defaultColumnTest.json']);
```

see screenshot of the records

row 1 is LOAD command with schema definition

row 2 is LOAD command without schema definition

row 3 is INSERT command as in your question above.

Hope this helps.

[image]